# How to change cursor propery of an online page?

Tags: html, css

To prepare my assignment, I came across a useful site where I could get some useful text. I wanted to copy some line of text from the page of the site,but cursor was not allowed there. What should I do to allow cursor for such pages?
                I tried by inspecting the element,but the attempt was unsuccessful. I used the same method that I often use to see password by changing input property from password to text.
         I want to know how to change cursor property of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable javascript from your browser , copy text and then enable it

Comment: Good one because they disable copy text by javascript code. This is a good answer and simple because you are not debugging or complicating your life.